# What kind of government organization does Alain de Benoist seek?

Tags: government, ideology, france, political-system, political-spectrum

Alain de Benoist's main focus is "identity".

This [article](https://www.liberation.fr/debats/2019/11/28/alain-de-benoist-faiseur-de-droites_1766127/) says that Alain de Benoist is both a "conservative and “socialist””. A [wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_de_Benoist#Orientation_politique) says that he is also a radical environmentalist; that he declared economic liberalism is its main enemy; that he was close to Russian far-right political philosopher Aleksandr Dugin; and that according to a political scientist, he participated in the spread of neo-fascism in France.

What kind of government organization does Alain de Benoist seek? Does he favor an authoritarian regime, or a totalitarian one? Did he say he was against democracy?

Comment: Wikipedia in English doesn't say he's a socialist. And the article you link to has that in quotes: "Conservative and “socialist”"/

Comment: @Fizz Thanks, I modified